# Draw line below/above line.new

Tags: pivot

Here is a script i'm using for detecting pivot point.
I'd like to draw a line at the close of the new detected pivot point, each time new pivot point are detected (and deleting other lines)

i try to change the line.new value to get the "close" but it didn't work

See the picture below, the blue lines i draw is what i'm searching to do :D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tnjc.jpg)

```
indicator("Pivot Points", overlay=true)

// Get user input
var devTooltip          = "Deviation is a multiplier that affects how much the price should deviate from the previous pivot in order for the bar to become a new pivot."
var depthTooltip        = "The minimum number of bars that will be taken into account when analyzing pivots."
threshold_multiplier    = input.float(title="Deviation", defval=2.5, minval=0, tooltip=devTooltip)
depth                   = input.int(title="Depth", defval=10, minval=1, tooltip=depthTooltip)
deleteLastLine          = input.bool(title="Delete Last Line", defval=false)
bgcolorChange           = input.bool(title="Change BgColor", defval=false)

// Calculate deviation threshold for identifying major swings
dev_threshold = ta.atr(10) / close * 100 * threshold_multiplier

// Prepare pivot variables
var line lineLast = na
var int iLast = 0 // Index last
var int iPrev = 0 // Index previous
var float pLast = 0 // Price last
var isHighLast = false // If false then the last pivot was a pivot low

// Custom function for detecting pivot points (and returning price + bar index)
pivots(src, length, isHigh) =>
    l2 = length * 2
    c = nz(src[length])
    ok = true
    for i = 0 to l2
        if isHigh and src[i] > c // If isHigh, validate pivot high
            ok := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] < c // If not isHigh, validate pivot low
            ok := false
    if ok // If pivot is valid, return bar index + high price value
        [bar_index[length], c]
    else // If pivot is invalid, return na
        [int(na), float(na)]

// Get bar index & price high/low for current pivots
[iH, pH] = pivots(high, depth / 2, true)
[iL, pL] = pivots(low, depth / 2, false)

// Custom function for calculating price deviation for validating large moves
calc_dev(base_price, price) => 100 * (price - base_price) / price

// Custom function for detecting pivots that meet our deviation criteria
pivotFound(dev, isHigh, index, price) =>
    if isHighLast == isHigh and not na(lineLast) // Check bull/bear direction of new pivot
        // New pivot in same direction as last (a pivot high), so update line upwards (ie. trend-continuation)
        if isHighLast ? price > pLast : price < pLast // If new pivot is above last pivot, update line
            line.set_xy2(lineLast, index, price)
            [lineLast, isHighLast]
        else
            [line(na), bool(na)] // New pivot is not above last pivot, so don't update the line
    else // Reverse the trend/pivot direction (or create the very first line if lineLast is na)
        if math.abs(dev) > dev_threshold
            // Price move is significant - create a new line between the pivot points
            id = line.new(iLast, pLast, index, price, color=color.gray, width=1, style=line.style_dashed)
            [id, isHigh]
        else
            [line(na), bool(na)]

// If bar index for current pivot high is not NA (ie. we have a new pivot):
if not na(iH)
    dev = calc_dev(pLast, pH) // Calculate the deviation from last pivot
    [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, true, iH, pH) // Pass the current pivot high into pivotFound() for validation & line update
    if not na(id) // If the line has been updated, update price & index values and delete previous line
        if id != lineLast and deleteLastLine
            line.delete(lineLast)
        lineLast := id
        isHighLast := isHigh
        iPrev := iLast
        iLast := iH
        pLast := pH
else 
    if not na(iL) // If bar index for current pivot low is not NA (ie. we have a new pivot):
        dev = calc_dev(pLast, pL) // Calculate the deviation from last pivot
        [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, false, iL, pL) // Pass the current pivot low into pivotFound() for validation & line update
        if not na(id) // If the line has been updated, update price values and delete previous line
            if id != lineLast and deleteLastLine
                line.delete(lineLast)
            lineLast := id
            isHighLast := isHigh
            iPrev := iLast
            iLast := iL
            pLast := pL

**// Get starting and ending high/low price of the current pivot line
startIndex = line.get_x1(lineLast)
startPrice = line.get_y1(lineLast)
endIndex   = line.get_x2(lineLast)
endPrice   = line.get_y2(lineLast)

// Draw top & bottom of impulsive move
topLine    = line.new(startIndex, startPrice, endIndex, startPrice, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)
bottomline = line.new(startIndex, endPrice, endIndex, endPrice, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
line.delete(topLine[1])
line.delete(bottomline[1])**

//plot(startPrice, color=color.green)
//plot(endPrice, color=color.red)

// Do what you like with these pivot values :)
// Keep in mind there will be an X bar delay between pivot price values updating based on Depth setting
dist = math.abs(startPrice - endPrice)
plot(dist, color=color.new(color.purple,100))
bullish = endPrice > startPrice
offsetBG = -(depth / 2)
bgcolor(bgcolorChange ? bullish ? color.new(color.green,90) : color.new(color.red,90) : na, offset=offsetBG)
```

Thank you

Changing the code

```
**// Get starting and ending high/low price of the current pivot line
startIndex = line.get_x1(lineLast)
startPrice = line.get_y1(lineLast)
endIndex   = line.get_x2(lineLast)
endPrice   = line.get_y2(lineLast)

// Draw top & bottom of impulsive move
topLine    = line.new(startIndex, startPrice, endIndex, startPrice, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)
bottomline = line.new(startIndex, endPrice, endIndex, endPrice, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
line.delete(topLine[1])
line.delete(bottomline[1])**
```